# How to disable/remove Times in time picker input box in angular by setting limits?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have time input box

```html
<input type="time" min="09:00" max="18:00" \>
```

I have set `min` and `max` attribute value as `09:00` and `18:00` respectively but it is not working.

I want to  remove or disable all the values other than `min` and `max` limits from time picker

Can you help me to fix the issue?

Comment: The `min` and `max` values are validated when the parent `form` element of the time control is submit - ([demo of that behaviour here](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/4eujh3cb/) - click the submit button). *It does not prevent the user from inputting values outside of those bounds.* To do that you would need to implement your own code.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work as you wanted but what it will do is if someone enters a value that is not between your `min` and `max`, it'll display an error and ask them to modify it before submitting. What you want is not possible as in 12 hours format every value comes twice.